# clang ICE's on Curiously recurring template pattern (CRTP)

Tags: clang, c++17

The following short program:

```
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
struct Ref {
    T& operator*() { return T::get(); }
};

template<typename T>
struct Repro {
    static T& get() { return table.back(); }
    inline static std::vector<T> table;
};

struct Type : Repro<Type> {};

struct Unit {
    Ref<Type> ut;
    Type& base() { return *ut; }    
};

int main() {}
```

Does not compile in clang (with -std=c++17), in what appears to be
an ICE. MSVC have no problem with it. *Does anything stick out as a
known clang bug, and is there a work-around?*

Being an ICE, this is probably not my fault, but that does not help
me, work is at a standstill atm.

View it online [here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/574eac84c62cc146)

Comment: This appears to be fixed in Clang 7. Can you update your Clang?

Comment: That needs to be approved, but now it probably will